# Script to Run as Admin

Tags: windows, administrator, altiris

I would like to create a script that will open a cmd prompt as admin and then run my exe, msi, or bat file.

my current scripted cmd is

```
msiexec.exe /i c:\temp\Cisco_Agent\CiscoAgentDesktop.msi /qn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [TechNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TechNet) article: [Runas command documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx)

From a command prompt:

```
C:\> runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator cmd
```

Or, if you're connected to a domain:

```
C:\> runas /user:<DomainName>\<AdministratorAccountName> cmd
```

---

Take a look [here](http://techtorials.me/windows/using-runas-with-a-password/) to learn how to use `runas` with a password automatically.

Comment: runas.exe cannot elevate if UAC is enabled, which will often be the case nowadays, especially as XP goes the way of the dodo.

Answer (score 0):

You can always walk around that one:

Create a shortcut to your script.
Go to Properties - Shortcut - Advanced- Check Run as Administrator

Every time you open the shortcut you will have your .exe opened with admin privileges.